# If $G$ is abelian, prove that the set of finite-order elements of $G$ is a subgroup of $G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$  be abelian group. Prove that $ H = \{g\in G : |g| < ∞ \}$ is a subgroup of $G$. By |g| we denote the order of the element $g \in G$.

**Proof:** Denote by $e \in G$ the neutral element in $G$ (which trivially lies in $H$). Now let $a,b \in H $ and assume that $|a| = m$ and $|b| = n$. Then because $G$ is abelian we have

$$(ab)^{mn} = a^{mn}b^{mn} = (a^m)^n(b^n)^m = e*e = e $$

So it follows that $ab \in H$.

Can someone please help me for proving $a^{-1} $ for any element $a \in H$, to conclude $H$ is a subgroup of $G$.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, let $a \in H$. As in your question, $a$ has finite order, i.e. $\vert a\vert = m$ for some $m \in \mathbb N$. Then it holds that $a^{m-1}*a = a^m = e$ and thus $a^{-1} = a^{m-1}$. Since you have already proven closure of $H$ under multiplication, it (inductively) follows that $a^{m-1} \in H$ and hence $a^{-1} \in H$.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint** The trick used in the statement of the question to prove closure under multiplication suggests a similar tack:

> Suppose $a \in H$ has order $n$, and evaluate $(aa^{-1})^n$ in two ways.

Answer (score 1):

**First critique**: Why do you say "suppose $e\in G$"? Isn't $e$ supposed to be the identity element of $G$?

**Second critique**: You haven't shown that $e\in H,$ yet (though this is simple), so how can you conclude that $ab\in H$?

**Hint**: One can prove that for any group $G$ and any $a\in G,$ we have $|a|=\left\lvert a^{-1}\right\rvert.$

Answer (score 0):

Consider the cyclic subgroup generated by $g$, which has finite order $n$. By a simple application of Lagrange every element of that subgroup has order which divides $n$, hence finite order.

Comment: Well someone put a down vote. It would be nice to know why. The subgroup generated by an element of finite order includes both the identity and the inverse of the original element.

Comment: Nice and simple argument, have a +1.